# How to find youtube videos by tag?

Tags: api, youtube

Do you know the way youtube search videos by tag? I posted some tags to video, but youtube didn't find this video by any tag that set to it.

Meta keywords has all the tags that i posted.

The main problem is that I try to find video by tag by youtube API, but it also didn't find the video. (http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER/uploads/-/TAG?v=2&alt=json).

Maybe there is a time that youtube needs to recache all videos tags?

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: this could be a delay in youtube data logistics, try giving it 24 hours and see again IMHO